# Sourcing a bashfile before running a command

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the following file **demo.env**:

```
export VALUE="abcd"
```

How can I make this works from a Mafile rule?

```
bash -c "source demo.env; echo $${VALUE}"
```

Comment: Do you need `bash -c` for this? Or is just running that via make normally acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently one way to do so is:

```
bash -c "source demo.env; echo \${VALUE}"
```

And in a Makefile rule:

```
echo:
    bash -c "source demo.env; echo \$${VALUE}"
```

Comment: Use single quotes around the argument to `-c` and you can avoid needing to escape the first `$`.